# Difference between unique and save unique in value

Tags: save, unique

The solution is:

```
dfrm1[ dfrm1$Name %in% dfrm2$Name , ]
```

I actually tried this one by myself before, but it didnt seem to work as I always checked

```
unique(dfrm1$name)
```

and it gave me back that I still have one thousand different firms instead of the expected 500. But now I used

```
dfrm1[ dfrm1$Name %in% dfrm2$Name , ]
```

without the negation as I wanted to keep all rows in dfrm1$Name that contain dfrm2$Name. Then I made the following. I saved my code unique(dfrm1$Name) in the new object x by doing

```
x <- unique(dfrm1$Name)
```

When I do

```
View(x)
```

I get the the correct 500 unique values, Even though just

```
unique(dfrm1$Name)
```

shows me  `Factor w/ 1000 levels "...."` in the right upper corner of `RStudio`.

Does anyone know the answer why only `View(x)` shows the correct values?

Comment: having 1000 levels doesn't mean you have 1000 elements, what's the result of `length(unique(dfrm1$Name))` ?

Comment: tell me if the answer below helps

Comment: you should keep details in your question, not as an answer. My answer gives the solution to this, it's to use `as.character` on your column. Or use the parameter `stringsAsFactor=FALSE` in your `data.frame` call as I advised as well in my second paragraph. I suggest you take some time to understand factors with simple cases. It's confusing at first but it's not that complicated in the end and it will help you many many times if you intend to continue to work with R.

Comment: I added a couple lines to my answer, hopefully making it a bit clearer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with a categorical variable, also known as a factor.

Character columns are read into factor if you use `data.frame`, `as.data.frame`, `read.table`... without setting explicitly `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. That may explain why you have to deal with this data type when it seems you'd rather not.

Elements from a `factor` vector can take a limited amount of values given by its `levels` attribute. These levels are displayed when you print `unique(dfrm1$name)` along with the values.

When you remove items from a `factor` vector, it keeps by default all levels including those that don't describe any element of the vector anymore.

See also `?droplevels`

To convert `factor` to `character`, use `as.character`.

See example below:

```
x <- factor(c("a","b"),levels = c("a","b","c"))
x # same output for unique(x)
# [1] a b
# Levels: a b c

levels(x)
# [1] "a" "b" "c"

length(x)
# [1] 2

length(levels(x))
# [1] 3

as.character(x)
# [1] "a" "b"

levels(as.character(x))
# NULL
```